# React & D3.js: re redering components causes re rendering of the same graph problems:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-state

I'm trying to make some reusable components in react with d3, the problem I'm having is that there are too many re renders as I have some states that change and should update the graph accordingly,

I have watched some videos about component optimisation on Youtube about useCallback ect...I know about the enter update exit phase of d3 and I know once i add in the exit phase it should in theory sort it ( i think ) however,

how do I stop so many re renders I must have made an error somewhere because it starts an infinite loop of re rendering the same graph component causing it to become really thick and black because it's stacking against the previous one.

the parent component: `StockLineGraph.js`

```
import React , { useState }from "react";
import LineGraph from "./LineGraph";
import useFetchAlphaVantage from "./useFetchAlphaVantage";
import LoadingSpinner from "./LoadingSpinner";
import styled from "styled-components";



const StockLineGraph = () => {

    const [tickerSymbol, setTickerSymbol] = useState("AAPL");
    const [yAxisTopic, setYAxisTopic] = useState("5. adjusted close");

    const [data, isLoading ] = useFetchAlphaVantage(tickerSymbol, () => true)

    return (
        <>

        {isLoading && <LoadingSpinner speed={.5}/> }

        <LineGraph 
            yAxisTopic={ yAxisTopic }
            tickerSymbol={tickerSymbol}
            data={data}
            args={() => ( isLoading === false)}
        /> 
        </>
    )
}

export default StockLineGraph;
```

And my custom hook to fetch the necessary data: `useFetchAlphaVantage.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect }from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useFetchAlphaVantage = (tickerSymbol, condition=() => true) => {

    const [data , setData ] = useState({});
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    const fetchData = async (tickerSymbol) => {

            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=${tickerSymbol.toUpperCase()}&outputsize=full&apikey=${api_key}`)

                for (const d in response.data["Time Series (Daily)"] ) {
                    for (const prop in response.data["Time Series (Daily)"][d]) {
                        response.data["Time Series (Daily)"][d][prop] = +response.data["Time Series (Daily)"][d][prop];
                    }
                }
                setData(response.data)
                setIsLoading(false);

            }catch(err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("re_rendered useFetchAlphaVantage")
        if (condition() === true) fetchData(tickerSymbol);

    }, [condition, tickerSymbol])

    return [data, isLoading];

}

export default useFetchAlphaVantage;
```

and my d3 code: `LineGraph.js`

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState, useRef }from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import styled from "styled-components";
import 
{
    select,
    scaleTime,
    scaleLinear,
    max,
    transition,
    extent,
    axisBottom,
    axisLeft,
    line,
    keys,
    values,
    easeLinear,
    entries

} from "d3";




const LineGraph = (props) => {

    let { args, yAxisTopic, data, tickerSymbol } = props;


    const svgRef = useRef();


    useEffect(() => {

        if (args === undefined) args = true;

        if (args() === true) {

            //d3

            const margin = {left: 50, right: 30, top: 30, bottom: 100};

            const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
            const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            const svg = select(svgRef.current)    
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .attr("class", "line-graph");

            const g = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

            const x = scaleTime()
                .range([0, width]);

            const y = scaleLinear()
                .range([height, 0])


            console.log(y(300))
            console.log(x(new Date("2000-06-15")))

            const xAxisCall = axisBottom(x)
            const yAxisCall = axisLeft(y)
                .tickFormat(d => { if (d === 0) return d; else return "$" + d} );

            //axis
            const xAxis = g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)

            const yAxis = g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y-axis")

            const yAxisLabel = g.append("text")
                .attr("class", "x axis label")
                .style("opacity", "0")
                .style("font-family", "Bebas Neue")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("y", 20)
                .style("font-size", ".9rem")

            //generate path
            g.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)




            const update = () => {

                const t = transition().duration(750); 

                x.domain(extent(entries(data["Time Series (Daily)"]).map(d => new Date(d.key)))).nice()
                y.domain( [0, max(entries(data["Time Series (Daily)"]).map(d => d.value[yAxisTopic]))] ).nice()

                //axis scales
                xAxisCall.scale(x);
                xAxis.transition(t).call(xAxisCall);

                yAxisCall.scale(y);
                yAxis.transition(t).call(yAxisCall);

                const lineFunction = line()
                    .x(d => x(new Date(d.key)) )
                    .y(d => y(d.value[yAxisTopic]) );

                g.select(".line")
                    .transition(t)
                    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                    .attr("d", lineFunction(entries(data["Time Series (Daily)"])))


                yAxisLabel
                    .transition()
                    .duration(750)
                    .ease(easeLinear)
                    .style("opacity", ".5")
                    .text(`${tickerSymbol} - ${yAxisTopic}`)
            }

            update();

        }

    },[yAxisTopic, tickerSymbol, args]);


    return ( 

        <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    )
}

export default LineGraph;
```

Comment: Have you tried using react [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)? Maybe wrap the component with memo to avoid changing the references? For instance `export default React.memo(LineGraph);`

Comment: yeah I did but it didn't work, sorry i should probably take down the post I solved it by for components that I didn't want to re render i put them in the return so that they don't get overridden...